# Prove that these infinite series converge simultaneously.

Tags: analytic-number-theory

An open problem in analytic number theory is to determine whether the sum

$\sum_n \frac{(-1)^n n}{p_n}$ converges.  Here, $p_n$ is the n-th prime number.

It is known that this sum converges if and only if the series

$\sum_{m=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{\pi(m)}}{m \log m}$ converges.

Here, $\pi(n)$ denotes the prime counting function.

Can anyone use the prime number theorem to prove that these two series converge simultaneously?

Comment: Hint: alternating series test combined with the prime number theorem giving asymptotics for $p_n$.